# Open link lists, attached and uploaded files in new tab

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, xml

I would like to know how can I edit in SharePoint 2010 Standard version so that when a user clicks on any link list item, uploaded or attached files in a announcement and document lists to be opened in a new tab (target="_blank")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery with something like

```
$('a').each(function() { this.prop('target','_blank'); });
```

If you want to limit it you can add .filter('.classname') or a jquery filter contains.

(Remember to have jquery available for this to work, you will need to upload and link jquery-latest to the site)

Comment: Since I am using Link lists only for external links I only want these and any PDFs in Document and and Announcement lists to globally open in new page. Every other link in a page I will handle manually

Comment: then you can use a combination of find() contains() other dom filters in jquery to get the ones you want. A good solution is to get the surrounding html with $('#surrounding') then use find to filter it $('#surrounding').find('a') something like that.